# Multiple Blog Feed

Tags: php, html, css

I hope you're having an awesome day.

Today I wanted to implement a blog on my site, write it on bloggr and when I post it, feed it to mysite.com/index.html  What would I need to be able to accomplish this! Help would be greatly appreciated!

I was searching around blogger and ended up in a configuration of it,

```
  1st. I get asked for my domain.
Then I have to replace the CNAMES...
```

-the blog just redirects to my domain with bloggr style...I want the blog to be displayed on one blog.mydomain.com/post-youre-watching 
I also want a div with the feed of the last 3 entries(despite the author)...How can I accomplish this? You guys know anywhere where I could find information on how to do this? If so, what information(or language) do I need to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to present the content on your site (rather then making your hostname point to Blogger) then you'll need to actually put it on your site.

The simplest way would be to periodically pull the data from the Atom or RSS feed hosted by Blogger and store the content in a database on your server.

You can then query it with your own server side code to get whichever combinations of data you desire.

Comment: http://alt-web.blogspot.mx/2011/06/adding-blogger-rss-feed-to-html-page.html I added this feed, but when the user clicks the title it redirects them towards bloggrs site, is there any way that I can create a html file with the name "post-title.html" with a certain html design? If so, what should I do?